# String parsing in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-parsing

I have a string like url params. I want to get **insurance** value if **insurance** param comes only one time in string.

**For example:**

**1.** Following string should produce result: **false**

> ?LastName=abc&FirstName=xyz&insurance=2&insurance=3&insurance=4&insurance=5&BirthDate=01-01-2000

**2.** Following string should produce result: **2** *(because only one insurance)*

> ?LastName=abc&FirstName=xyz&insurance=2&BirthDate=01-01-2000

How can I do this in JavaScript / jQuery

I appreciate every answer. Thanks

Comment: you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)?

Comment: @alliswell: Thanks. I used the top answer's function of question that you mentioned. It returns first **insurance** value without condsidering no. of **insurance** in string. I want to return **insurance** value only when there is only one **insurance** in the string. So now I have to add a check for the no of insurance in string.

Comment: you are welcome, and use regex as it mentioned or simple conditional check will work.

Comment: See also the [Query String Object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that will do what you want

```
function checkInsurance( queryString ) {
    // a regular exression to find your result
    var rxp = /insurance=(\d+)/gi
    if( !queryString.match( rxp ) || queryString.match( rxp ).length !== 1 ) {
        // if there are no matches or more than one match return false
        return false;
    }
    // return the required number
    return rxp.exec( queryString )[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @meouw - neat solution!

An alternative would be to use string.split. The following implementation is flexible about the param you are searching for and its value (i.e. any string).

```
function getUniqueParam (query, paramName) {
    var i, row, result = {};

    query = query.substring(1);
    //split query into key=values
    query = query.split('&');


    for (i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
        row = query[i].split('=');

        // if duplicate then set value to false;
        if(result[row[0]]) {
            result[row[0]] = false;
        }
        else {
            result[row[0]] = row[1];
        }

    };

    // return the requested param value
    return result[paramName];
}


// Testing:

var a = '?LastName=abc&FirstName=xyz&insurance=2&insurance=3&insurance=4&insurance=5&BirthDate=01-01-2000';
var b = '?LastName=abc&FirstName=xyz&insurance=2&BirthDate=01-01-2000';

console.log(getUniqueParam(a, 'insurance'));
console.log(getUniqueParam(b, 'insurance'));
```

Comment: There is a discussion on regex vs. string.split performance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966697/performance-question-string-split-and-then-walk-on-the-array-or-regexp)