# Three.js loading large models

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

When I try to load a very large file using the appropriate loaders provided with the library, the tab my website runs in crashes. I have tried implementing the Worker class, but it doesnt seem to work. Heres what happens:

In the main javascript file I have:

```
var worker = new Worker('loader.js');
```

When user selects one of available models I check for the extension and pass the file URL/path to the worker: (in this instance a pcd file)

```
worker.postMessage({fileType: "pcd", file: file});
```

Now the loader.js has the appropriate includes that are necessary to make it work:

```
importScripts('js/libs/three.js/three.js');
importScripts('js/libs/three.js/PCDLoader.js');
```

and in its onmessage method, it uses the apropriate loader depending on file extension.

```
var loader = new THREE.PCDLoader();
loader.load(file, function (mesh) {
    postMessage({points: mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array, colors: mesh.geometry.attributes.color.array});
});
```

The data is passed back successfully to the main javascript which adds it to the scene. At least for small files - large ones, like I said, take too long and the browser decides there was an error. Now I thought the worker class was supposed to work asynchronously, so whats the deal here?

Comment: what kind of error did you get?also what browser you used?

Comment: I doubt much is wrong per say. Very large model files lead to very large arrays in JavaScript THREE objects. Distributing those point, normal, material indexes, UV and face Arrays among many models by breaking up very large models into multiple files may help, depending on how large the models are. Also, using bufferGeometry may also improve runtime performance: See http://threejs.org/docs/api/core/BufferGeometry.html

Comment: @Alexus I tried chrome, opera, firefox, and IE. All except IE give a very unhelpful error (site crashed, oh snap, ect). IE just freezes.

Comment: @Radio Ive browsed the source files of affected loaders. Pretty much all of them load data into a string and then split it, if its not in binary. Its super inefficient. Its a shame such robust library have such poorly optimized file loading.

Comment: I understand your frustration. Very large files of any type in JS is difficult to master. Criticism of split is dubious http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966697/performance-question-string-split-and-then-walk-on-the-array-or-regexp How do you propose to load an ascii format file into JS and parse its content? This robust open source library as you say, is still in alpha. You're welcome to apply your loader improvements and submit them as pull requests. I'd be the first in line to try out faster parsing. Also, the loaders are supplied as is, not minified with the core. They are examples.

Comment: I reworked the PCD loader and made it load the data into uint8 array (which it actually did, but it used it to create a String object containing the entire file). But instead of creating a string out of it and splitting it (resulting in even more strings), said array is parsed - I collect the characters into a string with .fromCharCode until a space is found, and then parse the temporary string as a float and put it into a float32array containing appropriate data (position, colors etc). These arrays are then used as properties of buffergeometry.

Comment: Basically the only difference is that it avoids utilizing string.split() to fill the arrays passed to buffergeometry. Now that change was only applied to ascii part of the loader, the binary portion works without string arrays so I think it should be fine. I dont know if it loads things faster, but it certainly managed to load that 64MB file I mentioned in the answer without crashing the site (according to Opera, peak memory usage at 400MB). Ill consider submitting this, but Illl have to tidy up the code first.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Three.js's loaders rely on strings and arrays of strings to parse data from a file. They dont split files into pieces, which leads to excessive memory usage which browsers immediately interrupt. Loading a 64 MB file spikes to over 1 GB memory used during load (which then results in an error).

Comment: How do you propose JS discover where to safely split a 3d file without causing a corrupted geometry due to an automatic edge or vertex autocompletion?